# How to find the proper IPAddress to use to open a TCP/IP server port when there is many network adapters

Tags: c#, server, port, ip-address, network-interface

I can't find code to find the proper IP address to use to open a TCP/IP server port on my machine.

The problem occurs because I have many network adapters. I have some Virtual Machine(s) (for example: HyperV / VirtualBox / VmWare) which create virtual network adapter and each one has its one IPAddress. So how to avoid those IPAddress (proper network card) and find the only one used to access the internet for real?

When I try to find the proper IP Address, I get the virtual network adapter card Ip Adress instead of the physical one using this code:

```
IPAddress properIpAddress = null;

NetworkInterface[] interfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
foreach (NetworkInterface networkInterface in interfaces)
{
    var ipProps = networkInterface.GetIPProperties();

    foreach (var ip in ipProps.UnicastAddresses)
    {
        if ((networkInterface.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up) && (ip.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork))
        {
            if (ip.Address.ToString() == "127.0.0.1")
            {
                continue;
            }

            properIpAddress = ip.Address;
            // Console.Out.WriteLine(ip.Address.ToString() + "|" + networkInterface.Description.ToString());
            Debug.WriteLine(ip.Address.ToString() + "|" + networkInterface.Description.ToString());

            break;
        }
    }

    if (properIpAddress != null)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The real solution is to not search for an adapter in the first place.**

Just use `IPAddress.Any` to listen on all interfaces at the given port.

```cs
using(TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, somePortNumber))
{
    // some code
}
```

Comment: But that will open ports on all other network adapter? Not just the proper one?

Comment: Is there a reason you care about that? What defines a *"proper"* adapter anyway, as far as the network is concerned? Either you want to listen or you don't. In very particular circumstances (routers, Wifi controllers, VPN) then you ask the user which one

Answer (score -2):

I've been using the following code for this. It gets you the IP that an outgoing connection would use:

```
using (var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, 0))
{
    socket.Connect("8.8.8.8", 65530);
    IPEndPoint endPoint = socket.LocalEndPoint as IPEndPoint;
    return endPoint.Address;
}
```

Note however, that it does open a socket - so maybe one should cache the result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please note that I did not vote down your answer. You seems to open a client connection to a server "8.8.8.8". But my question is to find the ipadress that I should use to open a "server port for TCP". The main problem is to find the appropriate address because sometimes you can have many network adapter card with each a different IPAddress.

Comment: @EricOuellet Yes, I know. That piece of code gets you the IP of  the active network adapter.  It works by opening a  connection to the internet, and getting the local  address. By  opening a connection, you ensure that it's an active adapter as you wanted.

Comment: Also, why the downvotes? I know it's not the  **best** solution to the problem, but for anyone needing an easy way to get the IP of a local adapter connected to the internet, it works fine.

Comment: I did not downvote your answer. It is somebody else. I almost never downvote an answer because I think that answering takes time and effort and that should almost never be downvoted. But honestly, I think your answer is pretty offset from the question. But it is not me, and in extremely rare case where I downvoted, I always wrote a comment explaining why I downvoted.